# Send keys to WPF Browser control

Tags: c#, html, wpf, interop

Can I programatically send [UserID]{TAB}[Password]{CARRIAGE RETURN} to a webbrowser control which has a userID, password and Sign-in button there. I wanted to use my own virtual keyboard in my application. Any tips here?

Comment: My tip would be to use the accessibility features of the platform, rather than reinventing the wheel yourself. With javascript you should come a far way though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for the late answer but I've just finished a similar project and as part of the work am in the process of open sourcing two projects to Codeplex.

The first is the [Windows Input Simulator](http://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/) which is a simple .NET wrapper around the Win32 SendInput written in C#.

The second is a very customisable on screen keyboard or touch screen keyboard control and toolkit called WpfKB and will be available as an initial release tomorrow. Hope these are of help to you or anyone else who comes across the projects.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had to implement automatic authentication through a WPF browser control, and I looked into simulating keystrokes. I didn't need a full virtual keyboard so interacting with the DOM of the login page through [`IHTMLDocument2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752574(VS.85).aspx) ended up being the best approach, but I looked into keystroke automation before making that decision and found a few options.

1. You can raise the appropriate routed events on the control as described in [Simulating basic keyboard events](http://www.wpfwiki.com/WPF%20Q8.2.ashx) and [Simulating text input](http://ttp://www.wpfwiki.com/WPF%20Q8.2.ashx). I don't know of any specific problems with this approach but I opted against it simply because I wasn't comfortable simulating input without looking at how the CLR handles the actual input, and without at least raising the complete lifetime (PreviewKeyDown, KeyDown, PreviewKeyUp, KeyUp) I was wary of unintended consequences.
2. Take a look at [WOSK](http://wosk.codeplex.com/) on CodePlex. It's a good example of how to invoke Win32 [`keybd_event`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646304(VS.85).aspx) and [`SendInput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646310(VS.85).aspx) functions to generate the low-level input messages via [Managed Windows API](http://mwinapi.sourceforge.net/) to simulate input. There's some unnecessary fluff (eg transparency) and some odd WPF usage, such as using a `CommandParameter` with a `Click` event instead of a `Command` on the buttons, but the general approach is sane and it's reasonably complete.
3. You can also invoke the windows on-screen keyboard as alluded to by Jeroen. I didn't try this because I didn't need a virtual keyboard, but if you're going to call into Win32 anyway, you might as well follow the [WOSK](http://wosk.codeplex.com/) model and build the UI the way you want it.