# C# Send key inputs to Minecraft to move the player

Tags: c#, minecraft, sendkeys

I am trying to send keyboard inputs to Minecraft to move the player, however when I try using `SendKeys.SendWait("W");` nothing happens. If I open the chat in Minecraft it types "W" in chat, however outside of chat my inputs seem to be ignored. Thanks.

Edit: I have tried using `SendInput` as well as `InputSimulator` both having the same effect.

Comment: It's most likely because of DirectX it doesn't support passing window messages.. try this https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=inputsimulator or look into SendInput

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33793410/simulating-input-key-pressed-hold-and-release .

Comment: @SSpoke Thanks for the reply, but it seems I am having the same issue using InputSimulator.Keyboard.KeyPress

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved it by using InputSimulatorPlus

https://github.com/TChatzigiannakis/InputSimulatorPlus

`InputSimulator s = new InputSimulator();
s.Keyboard.KeyDown(VirtualKeyCode.VK_W);`

this just runs forward, to stop use `s.Keyboard.KeyUp(VirtualKeyCode.VK_W);`
you can also use `s.Keyboard.KeyPress(VirtualKeyCode.VK_W);` and this will just click  the "W" key.

Comment: Works as a charm, including mouse events. There is some pretty insane stuff that you can do if you combine both. This is far more advanced than putting a brick on a space bar or building a Lego machine to do some primitive key presses / clicks.

Answer (score 8):

Basically Windows has three [protection ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protection_ring). By doing `SendKeys` you are sending a ring 3 command to the application. However DirectX only listens to ring 0 and ring 1 (possibly ring 2) commands to reduce the fraction delay caused by command passing through a driver to application.

So in order to make DirectX games react to the event you sent you must send it at driver level. You can simulate a ring 2 driver input by pinvoke WINDOWS api [SendInput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput) with scan code (don't use virtual code).

If scan code doesn't work then the game might be blocking ring 2 commands for anti-hacking purpose. In that case you would need to write a driver + a virtual hardware to send ring 1 commands directly. (do not try this if you are not experienced. a Blue screen of death or even corrupted system may result if a mistake is made)